# MacOS Sonoma: Editing draft email problem, no input possible

Tags: mail.app, sonoma, text-input

Since updating to Sonoma, I have a very weird and annoying problem editing draft emails:

- I have a plain text draft email saved.
- If i then open it to edit the contents, I can move the cursor around, but if i put it at the beginning of an empty line, it often will ignore all keystrokes.
- If I press enter, a new line will be created and the cursor moves down. The input is still blocked, but now the last character pressed will appear on the old line (above the cursor).
- Only if I first press space or move to another section in the draft, I can add characters and edit the mail as usually.
- It might even be the case, that I can write text to certain lines of the draft, but not others.
- The problem does not happen consistently: Sometimes editing drafts works fine, sometimes not. Also, if the problem occurs, it does not happen in all empty lines but only some.

Additional info: Pretty much all 'intelligent' features such as spelling correction or the new autocomplete feature are disabled. My keyboard is German. MacOS is 14.2.1 (23C71), but I have had this problem with all versions since upgrading to Sonoma.

My hunch is, this might be connected to the url detection feature (not this new, super-annoying 'link preview' feature which I switched off, but just the normal url detection) in Apple mail which somehow might interfere with this new word prediction feature (although the latter is also disabled in the keyboard settings), but this is really just guessing.

Any hints anyone?

Comment: Hint only - I'm still trying to get the pattern: Seems to me that this happens when Mail is doing something like holding a sent message in its "Undo Send" cache or downloading a big batch of new messages. Do you notice anything like that? One other thing I've seen with drafts not accepting further edits is that opening them in their own windows, rather than in a panel of the main viewer, seems to allow immediate editing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I just edited my post to describe the behaviour better, it really is quite maddening and not easy to grok. Regarding your questions: I don't think this is related to any network activity, as I even have this problem when I'm offline. And yes, I open the drafts in a separate window (which is the only option for editing a draft, afaik). As just added above, my hunch is, something might be wrong with the url recognition in apple mail, but…

Comment: i added a screengrab for better understanding the behaviour: turn up the audio to hear me typing! https://imgur.com/a/Wazx9os

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I experience the same problem on two different MacOS computers. Both with Sonoma installed. I find that highlighting the "blank" section of the draft email with the problem and deleting it, then starting at the end of an existing line of text and pressing "return" gives me back the power of typing.